# Python округлить до 50 или 100

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как в python округлить число 478 до 500, а 472 до 450?

Comment: А какое полное задание? Если ли какие-то правила? А то по вашему вопросу только получится: `if n == 478: n = 500`

Comment: @0xdb: если не ясен мой ответ, вы можете комментарий к ответу оставить.

Comment: @0xdb вопрос был закрыт как "непонятный" (вы в списке голосующих) . Как следствие это значит что мой ответ не ясен. Если мой ответ не ясен, то оставьте комментарий к ответу: что именно не ясно.

Comment: @0xdb: у вас практически нет ответов по Питону (я вижу один), поэтому прежде чем закрыть вопрос как неясный, по не слишком знакомой вам метке, стоит на существующие ответы посмотреть (наличие которых очередь проверок показывает) или если лень, то нажмите кнопку "пропустить".

Comment: @jfs Я думал вопрос исчерпан. Или ещё  что-то не так?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Чтобы округлить до 50, можно умножить на 2 и округлить до 100:

```
def round50(n):
    return round(n * 2, -2) // 2
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/82no6P):

```
>>> round50(478)
500
>>> round50(472)
450
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
def round50(n):
    return round(n * 2, -2) // 2
    
def show(n):
    print(f"{n} -> {round50(n)}")
    
show(478)    
show(472)    

# try your own input    
from browser import document
@document["mybutton"].bind("click") 
def on_click(event):
    show(int(document["zone"].value))
</script>
<input id="zone" value="478"><button id="mybutton">round50</button></body>
```

Comment: не знал что есть `brython`. Интересная идея показывать результат выполнения питона через js-сниппет :)

Answer (score 1):

Округление до числа, кратного `x`:

```
round(i/x)*x
```

Вот пример работы для `x=50`:

```
a = [400, 425, 449, 450, 451, 499, 500]

for i in a:
    print("{} => {}".format(i, round(i/50)*50))
```

Вывод:

```
400 => 400
425 => 400
449 => 450
450 => 450
451 => 450
499 => 500
500 => 500
```

Comment: это сломается для больших целых. Попробуйте, `i=2**100`

Comment: да, сломалось. Правда не пойму в чем проблема. 
Но вряд-ли ТС нужно округлять такие большие числа

Comment: проблема в том, что целые в Питоне имеют бесконечную точность, а float конечную. Операция деления создаёт float (точность теряется).

Comment: да, округлять надо любые числа. В том числе и с запятой и большие тоже (до 100к)